# Prove if h(n) > f1(n) - f2(n) > 0 and f1(n) = Ω(g(n) and f2(n) = O(g(n)) then h(n) = Ω(g(n)

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

I proceeded as follows :

```
f1(n) > c1*g(n) , for all n>n1;  (*because f1(n) = Ω(g(n))*)
f2(n) < c2*g(n) , for all n>n2;  (*beacuse f2(n) = O(g(n))*)
Thus, h(n) > c1*g(n) - f2(n) > c1*g(n) - c2*g(n) > (c1 - c2)*g(n), for all n>max(n1,n2)
```

Now the problem is for h(n) = Ω(g(n)) to hold in accordance with my proof, c1 has to be greater than c2, because the constants in the O and Ω notation have to be positive. I am not able to eliminate that premise.

Can anyone please help me with that. Thanks

Comment: **Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with programming)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an actual coding problem.

Comment: I don't understand what big-O notation is ? Please point out what statement in my question contradicts the formal definition of Big-O ? I would be ever grateful . Also I thought time - complexity calculation relates to programming pretty much ! "Blatantly" just seems harsh there !

Comment: It is off topic (IMHO - I could be wrong, I admit) because it is not a problem with actual coding but with theory. It is so to speak a mathematical problem or a problem of theoretical methodology.

Comment: You could try http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ (but make sure to check what's considered on-topic there first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement does not look right to me.

Let `g(n)=n`, `f1(n)=n+1`, `f2(n)=n`, and `h(n)=2`.
Then `2 > 1 > 0` holds, but `h(n)` is obviously not Ω(n).

Comment: So yeah that premise can't be eliminated then. The example you provided me with is exactly a case in which c1 <= c2 and hence for h(n) = Ω(n), some c1 and c2 must exist such that c1 > c2. Thank you.